# How make change to print the least number

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to make a change in this program that print the max and least number at the same time?

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
int min;
int hour;
int max;
Console.WriteLine("\nenter hour");
hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
max = hour;
min = hour;
while (hour > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nenter 0 for exit");
    Console.Write("enter hour");
    hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (hour > max)
        max = hour;
    if (hour < max)
        min = hour;
}
Console.WriteLine("max: {0} ", max);
Console.WriteLine("minimium: {0}", min);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Don't post code as images.

Comment: solved
thanks its my first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are some errors in your code.

You want to exit the while-loop and get the result when the user inputs 0. However, 0 is still considered a candidate for `max`/`min` (and 0 is always smaller than the current `min`). Another problem is that when determining whether the current input is smaller than `min`, you instead compare it with `max`.

Regarding these errors, I have modified the code as follows:

```
while (hour > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nenter 0 for exit");
    Console.Write("enter hour");
    hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    // Exit the loop when the input is 0, without comparing it with max or min
    if (hour == 0)
        break;
    if (hour > max)
        max = hour;
    // hour should be compared with min
    if (hour < min) 
        min = hour;
}
```

Because you have `hour > 0` as the condition for the while-loop, the code behaves differently from what you have indicated in your description. When the input is smaller than zero, the while-loop will end while comparing it with `max` and `min`, which can output `max` or `min` as something smaller than 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to print them on the same line, you can put the second `Console.WriteLine({0}, x)` into the first by:

```
Console.WriteLine("max = {0}, min = {1}", max, min);
```

Don't know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks but 
no my problem is i want to print the least hour too. but its just print the most 
and it always print 0 for least